# Erro de NullInjectorError: No provider for

Tags: angular, angularjs-services, angular-providers

Estou tendo essa mensagem de erro:

```
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError[CervejaService]: 
  StaticInjectorError[CervejaService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for CervejaService!
    at _NullInjector.get (core.js:993)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1281)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1223)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1094)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1281)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1223)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1094)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10878)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:12110)
    at resolveDep (core.js:12608)
```

E tenho certeza que é por causa dessa linha de código:

```
import { Cerveja } from './../core/model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class CervejaService {

  cervejasUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/cervejas';

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  adicionar(cerveja: Cerveja): Promise<Cerveja> {
        return this.http.post(this.cervejasUrl,
        JSON.stringify(cerveja))
      .toPromise()
      .then(response =>  response.json());
  }
}
```

Como faço para saber o que esta retornando?
Teria alguma forma de aplicar nesse método um `console.log`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Você precisa adicionar o seu `CervejaService` na lista de `providers` do seu módulo.

Exemplo:

```
import { CervejaService } from './cerveja.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    // ...
  ],
  providers: [
    CervejaService, // seu provider aqui
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Ou então se não quiseres meter em todos os modelos que precises de serviços podes sempre fazer:

```
import { Cerveja } from './../core/model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root', // <---- Adiciona isto ao serviço
})
export class CervejaService {

  cervejasUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/cervejas';

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  adicionar(cerveja: Cerveja): Promise<Cerveja> {
        return this.http.post(this.cervejasUrl,
        JSON.stringify(cerveja))
      .toPromise()
      .then(response =>  response.json());
  }
}
```

Ao fazeres isto, não precisas de adicionar no `module` o service

Espero que ajude.